Get Siri to stop using special context for the word Radio
I am developing a streaming radio app and we are currently working on Siri integration.  The problem we are currently experiencing is that Siri is unable to play several of the stations because their name includes the word Radio.  When asked, "Hey Siri, play XYZ Radio on $app", she says, "I'm sorry, but I'm unable to find XYZ in your library."
The word Radio has a special context in Siri commands, and we would like to tell her to ignore that context when $app is included in the command or when the application is in the foreground.  How do I make this happen?
